# Use of multiple column name as input parameter or wild card in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would want to add an optional parameter to my stored procedure with default `*`. If the list of columns is provided [delimited by a comma] these columns should be returned back by the procedure. If the wildcard character is provided [star] `*`, all columns should be returned. Please let me know how to implement it.

Comment: **Show us** what you've tried so far! Where are you stuck? This is not a "write the code for me" service .... you need to put in some of your **own effort** first!

Comment: i am looking for ideas not code here.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - why stored procedure not table UDF?
Anyway it would be easier to pass null instead of "*" - tsql  allows default values on UDF parameters.
You would have to construct query dynamically and then use sp_executesql().
The issue is that you should validate columns list to prevent errors.